# Zend Framework 3 skeleton two module

Tags: zend-framework, module, zend-framework3

I'm following the zend framework 3 skeleton tutorial to the book.

I first got the application module working where it shows the standard welcome to zend screen.

When I added the album module everything went fine. When I navigate to /album in my url it displays the album section so all good there. However, when I remove the /album from the end of the url to get back to the application section I get the following 404 page.

```
**A 404 error occurred**
  Page not found.
  The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

 Controller:
 ApplicationController (resolves to invalid controller class or alias: 
 ApplicationController)
 No Exception available
```

I would show some sections of my code but at the minute I'm unsure as to what file could be causing this. If someone could tell me what config file is causing this issue then I can upload it. I'm pretty sure it's routing but coming from ZF1 it's a bit of a head scratcher.

If someone could help or explain to me where to look I would be very thankful.

**UPDATE**
Below is my module.config.php for my Application module.

```
   <?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendAlbumApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => \ApplicationController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'application' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/application[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**
When I replace the /album with /application in the url it shows the skeleton zend framework welcome page. I thought this page would show with just http://localhost? Am I missing the point or can I make the application module the default module so you don't have to add /application to the end of the url?

Comment: can you show your modules/application/config.php

Comment: Updated my original post.

Comment: I have just added /application to my url and it shows the zend framework page. I expected this page to show when there was no /application bit added to the url?

Comment: Could I be missing the point here and just need to set a default route up so that when I go to http://localhost. it shows the application module?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it. It seems like it was a newby mistake/typo.

I had to change the line:

'controller' => \ApplicationController::class,

TO

'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and telling me what page of code to upload.